# Automatically update a formula field based on checkbox

Tags: formula, field-update, automation

I have a date field that includes the day a position was opened and then I have a number formula field that calculates how many days the position has been opened: TODAY() - Date_Position_Opened__c

I created a checkbox for when the position gets filled. When that checkbox evaluates to true I would like the number of days open field to go null or even 0. Is this possible to do? I've tried going through process builder but my number of days open field won't come up as an option when its time to update, same with updating records on on flow. I started to do a validation rule but since the formula field is read only that doesn't make much sense to attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to use the `IF()` function to be able to make the formula do something different when a certain condition is met.

The gist of it is

- If your checkbox is checked (i.e. the value of the checkbox is `true`)
- Then return 0
- Else return the difference between today and the date the position was opened

Note that things like `IF(field == true, 'then value', 'else value)` can be reduced to `IF(field, 'then value', 'else value')`. When the field you're trying to check already is Boolean in nature, you can just use it directly in Boolean expressions.

While that would address the question as written, I get the feeling that you may actually want to keep track of how many days a position was open, and stopping that count when the position is filled. Things like that are what you would use a flow (probably a before-save, record triggered flow) for, and you'd need an additional field to store that information.

Comment: Thank you Derek! Yes I wanted to stop the count when the position was filled, which is why I thought to use process builder/flow but that may be above my skill set right now as I don't have much experience with before save flows.